# alternative greedy match

Tags: regex, greedy, regex-greedy, quantifiers

I want to make a **greedy** match to an alternative of either zero to 'm' consecutive occurences of 'a' or zero to 'n' consecutive occurences of 'b'. If I do

```
/a{,m}|b{,n}/
```

it will not work because when I have sequences of 'b', it will match with 'a{,m}', and the alternative 'b{,n}' will not be looked at, and it will not be a greedy match.

Comment: You're complaining that a regex does not look nice? :)

Comment: what pattern are you trying to match? I'm getting the impression that you don't understand what `[ab]` does.

Comment: Please give an example of the target string(s) you are trying to match against.

Comment: @zzzBov Altough I made a mistake in my regex, I think your impression is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, how about `/(?:a{1,m}|b{1,n})?/`

It'll match either a string of consecutive a's (up to *m* times), or a string of consecutive b's (up to *n* times), or nothing at all due to the optional `?`.

Comment: I think the problem in the original question is that for the sequence "aaaabbbb" @sawa wants to match the whole sequence, rather than just the "a" or "b" sections.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I wanted. Why didn't I come up with this? Nice. @glenatron Daniel's regex is what I wanted. Please wait 5 minutes for me to accept the answer.

Comment: @sawa Keep in mind that `a{1,m}` will match a substring when more than *m* a's are present, unless you somehow [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) your pattern (ie. `/a{1,4}/` will match the first four a's in `aaaaaaaaaa`)

Comment: I know that. I just want to match up to m, even if there is more.

Answer (score 0):

I think by default, quantifiers are greedy and from left to right. So its not really a greedy issue you were having its the a{0,m} in the alternation matching in the presence of non `a`'s. It would have matched up to 'm' a's had they been present first.

Greediness seem's more complicated than someone might guess.

'aaaaaaaaaa' =~ `/(a{1,2}) (a{1,2}?) (a{1,4}) (a{4,12}+)/x` &&
  print `"'$1', '$2', '$3', '$4'`";

`'aa', 'a', 'aaa', 'aaaa'`